# How do you convert screen coordinates to document space in a scaled SVG?

Tags: html, svg

I'm using the svg jquery plugin by Keith Wood, not the HTML5 canvas.

I define my svg image like this to scale my svg triangle image to fit its div container:

```html
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 299 215" >
    <g>
    <polygon points="1,1 299,1 149,210" fill="blue" stroke="blue" stroke-width="0" class="votenow"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

But how do I then match the coordinate systems?

I want to capture the mouse location at some point over the triangle and draw a circle at those X Y coordinates, but the circle gets drawn in a different location because the coordinate systems don't match.

So a circle would be drawn at point 10,10 but appear to be at 50,60 for example.

How do people cope with this?

Thanks.

Final Solution: Using the JQuery plugin to draw the circle and getScreenCTM() to calculate the points.

Perhaps I no longer require the JQuery plugin but it will do for now. Couldn't see how to do it using only the plugin.

```
$('#cvtriangle .tri').on( "click", function(e) {
    jqsvg = $('#cvtriangle').svg('get');
    svg = document.querySelector("svg");
    var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
    pt.x = e.clientX;
    pt.y = e.clientY;
    pt = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
    jqsvg.circle(pt.x, pt.y, 5, {class: 'vote', fill: 'white', stroke: 'white', strokeWidth: 2, cursor: 'pointer'});
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh535760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
It's my sample code.
For this usage, getScreenCTM method is very useful.

```html
    <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" onload="
        var c = document.getElementById('c');
        var cx = c.cx.baseVal;
        var cy = c.cy.baseVal;
        var svg = this;
        var point = svg.createSVGPoint();
        svg.onmousemove = function(e){
            point.x = e.clientX;
            point.y = e.clientY;
            var ctm = c.getScreenCTM();
            var inverse = ctm.inverse();
            var p = point.matrixTransform(inverse);
            cx.value = p.x;
            cy.value = p.y;
        };
    ">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="yellow"/>
        <circle id="c" r="10" fill="blue"/>
    </svg>
```

Comment: OK, I got it working using your example code to get the mapping and the JQuery SVG plugin to draw the circles.

Answer (score 12):

If you call the function `getScreenCTM()` on the SVG element, it will return the transform matrix used to convert document coordinates to screen coordinates.  You want the transform matrix for the other direction, so call `inverse()` on the matrix object.

```
var transform = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();
```

Now you can transform a point object to do the final conversion:

```
pt = pt.matrixTransform(transform);
```

[Working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rjzrw/)

```js
var x = document.getElementById("x"),
    y = document.getElementById("y"),
    svg = document.querySelector("svg");

svg.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
    var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
    pt.x = evt.pageX;
    pt.y = evt.pageY;
    pt = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());

    x.innerHTML = pt.x;
    y.innerHTML = pt.y;
}, false);
```

```css
#container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
div {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <svg version="1.0" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/>
    </svg>
</div>

<div>
    x = <span id="x"></span><br/>
    y = <span id="y"></span>
</div>
```

If the above version (using pageX/Y) doesn't work for you, try this version instead.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("x"),
    y = document.getElementById("y"),
    svg = document.querySelector("svg");

svg.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
    var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
    pt.x = evt.clientX;
    pt.y = evt.clientY;
    pt = pt.matrixTransform(evt.target.getScreenCTM().inverse());

    x.innerHTML = pt.x;
    y.innerHTML = pt.y;
}, false);
```

```css
#container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
div {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <svg version="1.0" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/>
    </svg>
</div>

<div>
    x = <span id="x"></span><br/>
    y = <span id="y"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason pt.x = evt.pageX didn't work but pt.x = evt.clientX did, so I went with defghi1977's answer. Cheers, and thank for the detailed answer.