# How do I convert DOM coordinate to SVG coordinate?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dom

I am trying to convert dom coordiante I get from the `ontouch` event(`clientX` and `clientY` more specifically) however I don't understand how I can do that.

I looked up at this example I found:
https://codepen.io/ehsanjso/pen/xNZgPE?editors=1010
and I didn't understood any of it.

Comment: That Codepen is one of the best interactive CTM explanations around... ``getscreenCTM`` is what you need

Comment: This answer shows the basics: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183727/how-do-you-convert-screen-coordinates-to-document-space-in-a-scaled-svg

Answer (score 1):

If the DOM and the SVG have the same dimensions, the coordinates in pixels and percent are the same. If one is bigger/smaller than the other the coordinates are the same in percent and different in pixels.
Example for calculating the X dimension:

#### Example 1

- DOM has a width of 200
- SVG Element has a width of 200
- Point in DOM at x: 50 => Point in SVG at x: 50 (25%)

#### Example 2

- DOM has a width of 200
- SVG Element has a width of 100
- Point in DOM at x: 50 => Point in SVG at x: 25 (25%)

Formula: `target_width * (point / width)`

I hope this helps to understand the basics, explaining the entire example you provided is a bit out of scope

Comment: how would the formula look in action for one of the example?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a coding service. People love to help you, but you need to help yourself first.